# Create an integer timestamp in Firebird

Tags: sql, casting, timestamp, firebird, epoch

I need a timestamp as an integer (please DON'T ask me why, I'm totally bothered by this). The definition is the number of seconds after 01.01.1970 as usual.

What I have as an inital value is a string with the format

YYYYMMDDHHMMSS (e.g. 20140108154821)

I've been able to build a normal timestamp

```
CAST(
(SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 5 FOR 2 )||'/'||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 7 FOR 2 )||'/'||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 1 FOR 4 )||' ' ||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 9 FOR 2 )||':'||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 11 FOR 2 )||':'||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 13 FOR 2 )||'.00'
) AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Then I tried to cast it into an int using this technique

```
CAST(cast(
(SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 5 FOR 2 )||'/'||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 7 FOR 2 )||'/'||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 1 FOR 4 )||' '|| SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 9 FOR 2 )||':'||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 11 FOR 2 )||':'||SUBSTRING ( t.thetime FROM 13 FOR 2 )||'.00'
) AS TIMESTAMP)
-cast('01/01/1970 00:00:00' as timestamp) as BIGINT) as TIMESTAMP_INT
```

I do get an integer, but it looks as if the returned value is the number of days or something like that.

e.g. 
08.01.2015, 16:33:01.114 becomes 16444

Any suggestions as why this happens or if there another way to do this?

I'm using a Firebird Version 2.5

Thanks in advance

PS:

```
SELECT 
CAST(cast(
    (SUBSTRING ( '20140108154821' FROM 5 FOR 2 )||'/'||SUBSTRING ( '20140108154821' FROM 7 FOR 2 )||'/'||SUBSTRING ( '20140108154821' FROM 1 FOR 4 )||' '
    ||
    SUBSTRING ( '20140108154821' FROM 9 FOR 2 )||':'||SUBSTRING ( '20140108154821' FROM 11 FOR 2 )||':'||SUBSTRING ( '20140108154821' FROM 13 FOR 2 )||'.00'
    ) AS TIMESTAMP)
    -cast('01/01/1970 00:00:00' as timestamp) as BIGINT) 
    from sometable

;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to use [`DATEDIFF`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-datediff):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(second, TIMESTAMP'1970-01-01 00:00', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

This assumes the time is UTC, otherwise you may need to offset by the timezone offset to compensate (eg for CET (UTC+1), you'd use `TIMESTAMP'1970-01-01 01:00'` instead).

Comment: Thanks a lot, after some testing this is the approach which is working for me :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you subtract two timestamps then the answer is the number of days between them. So what you want to do is to subtract the timestamp of the "big bang" from your timestamp and then to multiply with the number of seconds in a day, ie

```
SELECT floor((yourTIMESTAMP - cast('1970-01-01' as TIMESTAMP)) * 86400)
FROM rdb$database
```

replace the `yourTIMESTAMP` with your code which turns string into timestamp, the constant `86400` is number of seconds per day.

Comment: No, it should work OK. For example when subtracting '1970-01-01' from '1970-01-01 12:00' then the result is 0.5 (ie half a day = 12 hours).